# Reading in R a Seasonal Polar Season Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to understand how to read the amount being measured in a Polar Seasonal Plot.

REPREX:

```
library(tidyverse)  
library(fpp2)       

ggseasonplot(a10, polar = T)
```

RESULT:

[image]

For example, by looking at the plot how would I know the amount (in millions) that was sold on July 2008? On the left hand side of the plot I only see two dashes for 10 and 20 million, should the distance between 10 and 20 be my scale of 10 million?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does seem like poor plot design - it's more common in polar plots to label lines directly. I think the 10 and 20 are indicating distances from the center horizontal line (Oct-May), and if you imagine horizontal lines extending from the 10 and the 20, those line up as tangent to the faint gridlines. Unfortunately, the 10 is closer to the center than the 20, suggesting either the scale isn't linear or (more likely) doesn't start at 0 in the center.

I've annotated the plot here with the horizontal lines and circling the tangents.

You could use `annotate` or `geom_text` to add labels directly to the plot, and use `theme()` to make the grid lines a little more obvious.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I've considered what you've said before, but that's why in my original question I'd like to know how to read for example Jul 2008,  how I quantify that from the plot?

Comment: Use the radial gridlines with the info I mentioned. The middle gridline is 20, the inner gridline is 10. July 2008 is a little outside the 20 gridline, eyeballing it I'd place it's value at about 21.5.

Comment: Opening it up in an image viewer, there are about 20.5mm between the 10 and 20 gridlines, and a little under 3mm between the 20 gridline and July 2008. So 3.8 / 20.5 * (20 - 10) = 1.85, so a better estimate would be 21.85. I was pretty close with the 21.5 though.

Comment: I believe I understand what you are doing now thanks! As you said before though, it's hard to decipher the region between the center up to 10, especially since the distance from the center to 10, and then 10 to 20, are not equidistant. I guess you just have to eyeball it and make a guess.

Comment: In `ggplot2` is just a regular plot that is stretched into a circle - bringing opposite edges together. And the default line plot is does not have the y-axis start at 0. My guess is that default was used here, so indeed the center is not 0. You may be able to add `expand_limits(y = 0)` to the plot to make it start at 0 in the center.